# unable to install Miniconda on macOS Sonoma

Tags: miniconda

I have issues installing Miniconda. I get the following error.

```
 % brew install --cask miniconda
==> Caveats
Please run the following to setup your shell:
  conda init "$(basename "${SHELL}")"

Alternatively, manually add the following to your shell init:
  eval "$(conda "shell.$(basename "${SHELL}")" hook)"

==> Downloading https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py311_23.10.0-1-M
Already downloaded: /Users/yannik/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/411db92e462c43c07802dccd5bec0bdf49e38497f945c1ceaf3ead78e164d6ff--Miniconda3-py311_23.10.0-1-MacOSX-arm64.sh
==> Installing Cask miniconda
==> Running installer script 'Miniconda3-py311_23.10.0-1-MacOSX-arm64.sh'
PREFIX=/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base
Unpacking payload ...
/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/py311_23.10.0-1/Miniconda3-py311_23.10.0-1-MacOSX-arm64.sh: line 340: 27018 Done                    extract_range $boundary1 $boundary2
     27019 Killed: 9               | "$CONDA_EXEC" constructor --extract-tarball --prefix "$PREFIX"
==> Purging files for version py311_23.10.0-1 of Cask miniconda
Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/env PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/shared:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/py311_23.10.0-1/Miniconda3-py311_23.10.0-1-MacOSX-arm64.sh -b -p /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base` exited with 137. Here's the output:
PREFIX=/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base
Unpacking payload ...
/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/py311_23.10.0-1/Miniconda3-py311_23.10.0-1-MacOSX-arm64.sh: line 340: 27018 Done                    extract_range $boundary1 $boundary2
     27019 Killed: 9               | "$CONDA_EXEC" constructor --extract-tarball --prefix "$PREFIX"
```

Honestly, I have no idea what this means. It seems like `extract_range $boundary1 $boundary2` is causing a process to be killed. I don't know how to fix this.

I can install this if I run sudo brew install --cask Miniconda but I don't want to use sudo. It'll make permissions a mess later on. Also it's specific to Miniconda because I can install Miniforge just fine.

Has anyone figured out how to fix this?